# Writng to a txt

Tags: java, filewriter

I have a txt file, I want to scan it and get from it a specific data and write the result in another txt file.
It works for my with system print line only.
Writing in the new txt file I created doesn't work for me, I would appreciate if someone can let me know what I'm missing !

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadingFile {

@SuppressWarnings({ "resource", "unused" })
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // reading a current txt file
    File file = new File("C:/Users/Aboelmagd/Desktop/myfile1.txt");
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String reading;

    // Creating new txt to get the result
    File newFile = new File("C:/Users/Aboelmagd/Desktop/my.txt");
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(newFile);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
    String writing;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(reader);

    // Scanning myFile.txt and writing to my.txt
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        writing = sc.next();
        // copying the full of myFile.txt to my.txt
        //bw.write(writing); 
        //bw.newLine();
        // If type is found, cet it and write to my.txt
        if (writing.contains("Type:")) {
            writing = writing.substring(0);
            // printing is working, yohooo :D
            System.out.println(writing);
            // writing to the my.txt is not working ?!!!
            bw.write(writing);
        }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an exception or what means `it doen't work`?

Comment: Add `bw.close();` after your `while` loop.
That's when the file gets written on disk.

Comment: @Jens
The thing is, I don't get any exceptions, and I mean by it doesn't work, after I run the code, the my.txt still empty !!

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla
Thank you so much, this fixed my issue
It was so simple to think about :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless and until you call the close() method of the writer object, the contents will not be physically written to the real file. Always, close the writer after your writing tasks are over. In your case, call

```
 bw.close();
```

after your while loop closes.